# Creating 4 part color ramp in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, color-ramp

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1. I am trying to create a custom color ramp that only has 4 colors, as defined by the company I work for. I am trying to create the color ramp through the Style Manager but the pre-set colour ramp has 13 spaces for color however I only need 4.

Does anyone know a simple way I can create and save a custom colour ramp with only 4 colors?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from here using a Multi-part color ramp with four Algorithmic color ramps inside.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the layer symbology properties.
2. Show as stretched.
3. Pick some random color ramp.
4. Right click the color ramp to open the Edit Color Ramp dialog box.
5. Add or remove color ramps as necessary to ensure the you have four Algorithmic Color Ramps showing in the editor.
6. Highlight the top most algorithmic color ramp and click properties.
7. Select the radial button for Color 1 and change this color to your custom color.
8. Select Color 2 and change this color to your second custom color.
9. Choose OK.
10. Select the second color ramp and repeat the steps above except now color one here becomes your original custom color two and color two becomes your custom color three.
11. Repeat these steps for the other color ramps.

By making the end of one color ramp the same color as the start of the next color ramp you can make a smooth algorithmic color ramp.  When everything looks good and you are back to the layer properties, right click your new ramp and select save to style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Esri products:

- right click on the layer
- go to properties
- click on the symbology tab
- under quantities you can select the number of classes you'd like